# How to set different menu other than Homepage?

Tags: wordpress, menu

I want to set different menu in pages except Homepage.
How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: please provide more info. as an exercise, read up on localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First register your menus

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

```
register_nav_menus( array(
 'homepage_menu' => __( 'Home Page Menu' ),
 'page_menu' => __( 'Page Menu'),
) );
```

and next use bellow code block in your theme

https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

```
if ( is_home() ) {

    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'homepage_menu',
        )
    );

} else {

    wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'page_menu',
        )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set different menu in pages you can do by the setting condition for pages something like this:

```
if(is_front_page()){  // to disply in home page
   wp_nav_menu();  // first menu
}
else if(is_page($pageid)){ // set by page id to display only for specific page
   wp_nav_menu(); // second menu
}
else {
   wp_nav_menu(); // third menu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: You have to register 2 menu, one for homepage/front-page other for others pages. This code add your functions.php file.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    //'home' is your menu slug/id that use for home or front page
    'home'      => 'Your menu name',
    //'pages' is your menu slug/id that use for other pages
    'pages'     => 'Your menu name', 
));
```

Next step: Add below code in your header.php menu section area.

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'pages' ) && !is_home() && !is_front_page() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'pages',
        'container'       => false,
        'menu_class'      => 'your-menu-container-class',
    ) );
}else if ( has_nav_menu( 'home' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location'  => 'home',
        'container'       => false,
        'menu_class'      => 'your-menu-container-class',
    ) );
}
```

May be it will solve your problem